# Java transaction with multiple inserts not rolling back

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert data into multiple tables in Java. If the insert fails in 1 table, it should rollback the data in all tables. But for some reason, the data is inserting into 2 tables and not inserting into 1 of them. It shouldn't be inserting into the other 2 since the insert failed on one of the tables. This is what my code looks like:

```
try {
     conn.setAutoCommit(false);

     dbConnector.insertA(myList1, conn);
     dbConnector.insertB(myList2, conn);
     dbConnector.insertC(myList3, conn);

     conn.commit();
} catch(SQLException e) {
     try {
          conn.rollback();
          e.printStackTrace();

     } 
     ...
}
```

And inside the insert methods:

```
public void insertA(List<MyClass> myList1, Connection conn){
   String myQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE (colA, colB, colC) VALUES(?,?,?);";
   PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(myQuery);

  for (MyClass mc : myList1) {
    statement.setString(1, mc.getA());
    statement.setString(2, mc.getB());
    statement.setString(3, mc.getC());
    statement.addBatch();
  }
   statement.executeBatch();
   statement.close();
   conn.close();

   ...
```

}

Note: `insertB` and `insertC` methods follow the same pattern as `insertA`.

Where did I go wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should not close connection before calling commit() or rollback(), some databases might implicitly commit in this case.

Comment: I wonder if you code is right `conn.close();` inside `insertA` is completely unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

As per the javadoc for [java.sql.Statement.executeBatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch())

> If one of the commands in a batch update fails to execute properly,
>   this method throws a BatchUpdateException, and a JDBC driver may or
>   may not continue to process the remaining commands in the batch.

It would seem your flavor of driver continues to process the remaining commands after an explosion, and to achieve that it must open a new transaction in which to execute the remaining statements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes - that's the exception I was getting on the table where it wouldn't insert. I'm trying to insert to `DB2`. Everything processes successfully if I don't insert in batches. But once I add the code to insert in batches, it fails.